# Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace PROCEDURE check_stock_qty
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN
    ( SELECT P_ID FROM product WHERE PRODUCT.p_value < 50
    )
    LOOP
      apex_mail_p.mail
      (
        'raavimistry@gmail.com',
        'ravimistryof180@gmail.com',
        'TEST',
        '( r.P_ID )');
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: Erm, what is your question? I think oracle has a "show errors" command you can issue for more details.

Answer (score 3):

To find the errors on your object, try

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'CHECK_STOCK_QTY'
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `IS` or `AS` after the procedure name:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE check_stock_qty IS
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `AS` keyword

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_stock_qty
AS
BEGIN
   FOR r IN (SELECT P_ID
               FROM product
              WHERE PRODUCT.p_value < 50)
   LOOP
      apex_mail_p.mail ('raavimistry@gmail.com',
                        'ravimistryof180@gmail.com',
                        'TEST',
                        '('|| r.P_ID ||')');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Beat you by 5 seconds.  :p